# Save attribute data with same value in Cygnus & STH-Comet

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-sth-comet

I created the subscription in Orion to save data via Cygnus in STH-Comet.
Is there a way to save data when a client updates the attribute with the same value?

Comment: I imagine that it must be solved in the subscription. I'm thinking of setting a sub on the timestamp of the attribute, but I don't know if there is another good solution

Comment: I'm using the alterationTypes (entityUpdate) in the subscription.subject.condition, but doesn't work!

Comment: I'm using the Orion 3.7.0 version

Comment: I want to store any attribute that it will post into Orion (independently if the future attribute is changed or equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have two ways to make Orion sending notifications even when the attribute value doesn't change at update time (assuming that the attribute is covered by the subscription, of course ;)

- Use the `forcedUpdate` option in the update request, eg. `POST /v2/entities/E/attrs?options=forcedUpdate`. This feature was introduced in Orion 2.2.0.
- Include `entityUpdate` in the `alterationTypes` field in the subscription (check more information on this in [Orion API documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#subscriptions-based-in-alteration-type)). This feature was introduced in Orion 3.7.0, although some later fix was done in Orion 3.8.0.

The first may require modification on clients. The second one probably is better, as it is configured in the subscription.

In any case, I'd recommend you to upgrade Orion Context Broker to the newest version (today that is 3.11.0, but in a couple of days Orion 3.12.0 will be released).

Comment: Thank you, Fermin. It worked with my config above (alterationTypes) but for the 3.11.0 Orion version